# PHP pthreads синхронизация потоков

Tags: php

Пожалуйста, объясните на русском языке, как и для чего используются методы `Threaded::synchronized()`, `Threaded::wait()`, `Threaded::notify()`, `Threaded::notifyOne()`?
Как вообще работает эта синхронизация?
Почему последние три должны быть всегда в блоке synchronized()?
Я уже перечитал много статей на английском, я до сих пор не могу понять..
Что будет если сделать синхронизацию к одному потоку из нескольких?